# PHP Random Text - Is there a better, cleaner, or less server-intensive solution?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ssi

Can the following `random_text` function in PHP be done with a better method, e.g. Javascript, jQuery, SSI, etc.? I am looking for a method that is the quickest to render and is the least intensive on the server for faster page loads. Or, is PHP is the best method?

```
$random_text = array("Random Text 1",
                "Random Text 2",
                "Random Text 3",
                "Random Text 4",
                "Random Text 5");

print_r($random_text[array_rand($random_text)]);
```

Comment: Does it matter if the client can view the source of the webpage and see all the random text entries?  If not, just use Javascript (either vanilla or the library of your choice) so you make the client do all the work.

Comment: How many text values do you have? for those 5 values difference would be negligible

Comment: I hope you've benchmarked this and found it to be some kind of bottleneck. The best way to do this is whatever way it's already working, unless you've found it actually has some measurable impact on the performance of your site. Chances are pretty good that (for five items) it doesn't.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ & meager It's just five values and it's not slowing anything down, so it looks like I'll stick with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it using jQuery on the client side:

```
var result = random_text[Math.floor(Math.random()*random_text.length)];
```

Comment: Yes, if the knowledge of all the possible random strings available to the asker's clients do not need to be secure.

Comment: Following the question, for a better method using eg. js or jQuery I take for granted, that there is no problem with the source.

Comment: Client side viewing the source code isn't an issue for me and although I'm still using PHP because the difference is negligible as advised in the question comments, I'll accept your answer in hopes that I'll help someone who has a project with more random values. Thanks!